# JQuery/Javascript is not getting triggered after page is refreshed while using window.onload function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
            var cookieBanner = document.querySelector('#onetrust-consent-sdk');
            if (cookieBanner) {
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                  var hT = $('.footer__corporate-tout').offset().top,
                  hH = $('.footer__corporate-tout').outerHeight(),
                  wH = window.innerHeight,
                  wS = $(this).scrollTop();
                  console.log(wS + ' ' + (hT + hH - wH));
                  if (wS >= (hT + hH - wH)) { 
                    $('#banner-sdk').addClass("footerBottom");
                    $('#consent-sdk').addClass('p-20');
                    if ($('#close-btn-container').children().length > 0) {
                      $('#banner-sdk').addClass("hasCrossIcon");
                    } else {
                      $('#banner-sdk').removeClass("hasCrossIcon");
                    }
                  } else {
                    $('#banner-sdk').removeClass("footerBottom");
                    $('#consent-sdk').removeClass('p-20');
                  }
                })
              }
          })
```

I am using window.on load function instead of document.ready function because the banner is getting loaded as external js and I don't have option of rearranging the execution of js. So  the above code is working fine for the first time when the site loads but not while refreshing the page/site

Comment: I am using jQuery version of 3.5.1 and it is not working in any of the browser like chrome or firefox

Comment: I have a external cookie banner getting loaded to my site. So once the site is scrolled to the footer to a certain div then the position of the cookie banner is changed using the class name getting added through javascript. It is an external plugin so on using document.ready or document.onload the functionality is not working as the js file is getting loaded before the cookie banner gets loaded